# pig error: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING - Generic solution

Tags: apache-pig

A typical Pig error that occurs without much usefull information is the following:

```
Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
```

Often found in a line like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Job in state DEFINE instead of RUNNING
```

I have seen some examples of this error, but would like to have the generic solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

So far, at each occasion where I have encountered this error, it is because Pig fails to load files. The error in the question is printed to *stderr* log, and you will not find anything usefull there.

However, if you were to look in the *stdout* log, you would expect to find the following:

```
Message: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 2118: Input Pattern hdfs://x.x.x.x:x/locationOnHDFS/* matches 0 files
```

Typically followed by:

```
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input Pattern hdfs://x.x.x.x:x/locationOnHDFS/* matches 0 files
```

At this point the most likely suspects are:

- There are no files in the specified folder (though the folder exists)
- The user that is running the script does not have the rights to access the relevant files
- All files are empty (not sure about this one)

---

Note that it is a commonly known difficulty that pig will error out if you try to read an empty directory (rather than just processing the alias with 0 lines).